# Get from the string only the first row

Tags: php, regex, php-5.3

I have this string:

```
error_id: 44
error_de: wrong number : 565
```

Now I want to get every occurrence of the value of `error_id`. How can I do that?

Comment: `preg_match('~error_id:\s*\K\d+~', $string)`

Comment: Including `error_de` as well?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

if (preg_match('/error_id: (\d+)/', $string, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches);
}
```

I think you will want to make use of `$matches[1]` but I can't remember offhand!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php   

    // Your string.
    $string = 'error_id: 44 error_de: wrong number : 565';

    // Find the error id from your string ($string).
    if(preg_match('/error_id\:\s+([\d]+)/', $string, $matches))
    {

        // Echo out the error id number
        echo $matches[1];

    }
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php for more information on preg_match.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use preg_match**_all** because there is more than one (if I understand correct?)

```
preg_match_all("/error_id:\s+(\d+)/", $theString, $errorIDs);
Var_dump($errorIDs[1]);
```

Working example, click preg_match_all
http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fMH

Edit: if you need the "wrong number" part too use this pattern: `error_id:\s+(\d+).error_de: (.*) : (\d+)`